# Pass command arguments to package.json scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, command-line-arguments

I have a MERN app that's divided into a `server` and a `client` folder, as well as a root `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "server": "cd server && npm run start",
    "client": "cd client && npm start",
    "install": "cd server && npm install && cd ../client && npm install"
}
```

Then, inside my `server` file, I have another `package.json` with the following scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon app.js"
},
```

What I want to do is to pass a IP address as a command argument to my main `start` script, to then use that IP inside my server's `app.js`, like so:

`npm start 0.0.0.0 // This is the 'start' in the root package.json file, not the one in my server`

How can I archieve this?